# ToolBar kendo UI error

Tags: kendo-ui-grid

I am trying to export kendo grid data in excel format but getting an error. Here's the image:

[image]

I think it would be pretty clear with the picture as to what the error is. What could I be missing here?

Comment: What version of Kendo are you using?  I can't remember exactly what version Excel export was introduced, but it has not been there since the beginning....Looks like it was introduced 2014 Q3.

Comment: Version-2014.2.716.440.   Runtime version-v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel functionality was not introduced until version 2014.3.1119(released Nov. 19, 2014).  You will have to update to at least that version to have access to .Excel().

Comment: Where can I get the latest dll from. I have tried searching over but couldn't find one. Can you please provide some link. I will mark your answer then.

Comment: No, I cannot.  The Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC(i.e. razor helper version) is a paid product from Telerik.  If you are a licensed user, simply download it from your account.  If you are not(or were not) a licensed user, then you shouldn't even be using the DLL.  The jQuery version of Kendo UI Core is open-source but does not include the MVC helpers and does not include "premium" controls like the Grid.  See http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison.  UI for ASP.NET MVC is the equivalent of Kendo UI Professional with MVC/Razor.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try to get a license then.